# Converting ROOT Tree to HDF5

Tags: data-analysis, data-sets

I have a TTree in [ROOT](https://root.cern.ch/) with 1000 events and 15 variables associated to each of them. I would like to convert this in its entirety to an hdf5 dataset. How do I organise my data in HDF5 Groups such that I can access data both by event number and by variable (if I wanted all the data from the '*kinetic energy*' variable, for example, all events)?

Note: I have already tried the [root2hdf5](http://www.rootpy.org/commands/root2hdf5.html) conversion tool but this does not work for branches with arrays/compound datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give a try to [DataHarvester](https://github.com/WolfgangWaltenberger/dataharvester).

This tool claims to support ROOT, HBOOK, HDF, XML, SQLITE and input/output between them.

See the following publication:

- [W. Waltenberger, G. Richter, and H. V. Riedel, "DataHarvester—an abstraction layer for accessing scientific data from various sources," in *Int. Conf. Computing High Energy Nuclear Phys.*, Victoria, Canada, Sep. 2007, pp. 1-4.](http://doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/119/4/042033)